# Получение данных EditText активности из фрагмента

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

Добрый день.
В приложении на имеется два фрагмента которые динамически заменяют друг друга. 
В активности к которой они прикреплены есть два edittexta.
Один из фрагментов помещается в backstack также он появляется при нажатии на кнопку в активности. И в зависимости от того какие данные сейчас в edittext активности он выполняет свои функции.
Как правильно реализовать запрос к edittext, которые находятся в активности, из фрагмента при его появлении? Сейчас я это сделал следующим образом но не уверен что он правильный.

```
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    CustomEditText etFrom = (CustomEditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.searchFrom);
    CustomEditText etTo = (CustomEditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.searchTo);
    String From = etFrom.getText().toString();
    String To = etTo.getText().toString();
    if (From.equals("") || To.equals("")){
        pbLoad.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tvInformFragment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (stationFrom.equals("")){
            tvInformFragment.setText(INF_ENTER_FROM);
        }
        else {
            tvInformFragment.setText(INF_ENTER_TO);
        }
    }
    else {
        pbLoad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvInformFragment.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        loadData();
    }
}
```